# Test::More failing test with equal strings

Tags: unit-testing, perl, test-more

Using perl 5.16 with the latest Test::More module.

I got a unit test being called like

```
is($ret, "ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.187 port 22: Network is unreachable\nCouldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer\n", "putFileWithSFTP bad server ret test");
```

Running the test fails with the following result:

```
#   Failed test 'putFileWithSFTP bad server ret test'
#   at t/Backup.t line 891.
#          got: 'ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.187 port 22: Network is unreachable
# Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
# '
#     expected: 'ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.187 port 22: Network is unreachable
# Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
# '
```

The strings should be equal and they also look like they are equal. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: MSWin line ends or some other invisible characters? Try running the strings through `join " ", map ord, split //, $string` or something similar.

Comment: Was (for whatever reason) MSWin line endings. Found it when comparing the hexdump. Writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

When comparing the two strings with a hexdump, I noticed that, for whatever reason, the ssh ouput in `$ret` contains MSWin Line Endings, which I didn't include in my comparison.

More can be read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645031/redirect-ssh-output-to-file-changes-line-endings)